# Get time in GMT in a specific format

Tags: python, date, time, gmt

I want a time in the below-mentioned format, using Python.

```py
Tue, 08 Nov 2022 15:35:20 GMT
```

1. I should be able to get the current time in above format;
2. Then I should be able to add days in it and get the date and time in the same above-mentioned format (for example, I want date falling on after `n` number of days).

Any help would be highly appreciated.

I have tried the below code but not getting the desired results:

```py
start_date = str(datetime.now()).split(".")[0]
due_date = str((datetime.now() + timedelta(days=2))).split(".")[0]
```

Output:

```py
2022-11-08 23:45:15
2022-11-10 23:45:15
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

Comment: You probably are looking for `datetime.utcnow().strftime('%a, %b %m %Y %T GMT')`.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use the below functions:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def get_now():
    return datetime.now().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')

def n_days_from_now(n):
    now = get_now()
    return (datetime.now() + timedelta(days = n)).strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')
```

Comment: Thanks @Mateus for taking out your time. With your code I am getting the output as:
Fri, 11 Nov 2022 GMT

Time is missing in the output.

Comment: Able to get the time using '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT'

Comment: try it again now please

Comment: All that back and forth conversion doesn't make any sense. Just use `datetime` objects and convert it to string in the desired format when you need to present them to the end user. Also, what is the point of creating a function to get the `datetime.now()` object when you can simply call it right away?

Comment: Also, why import `date` if you are not using it?

Comment: accdias, better now?

Comment: This `datetime.now().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')`  is not doing what you think it is doing. :-) Go check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now). Hint: it is not giving you the `datetime` in `GMT`.

Comment: Yeah i had noticed I'm getting the local time, but i also notice the GMT think is not really a pre requesite of the question so I just code like that. 
Whoever want to use the code may change the GMT part of the code or even use a variable to select the meridian.

Comment: Just one more hint: `%T` is a shorter way to get `%H:%M:%S`.